# minimizing function calls inside dynamic sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I get rid of the multiple convert functions in the following dynamic SQL?

```
IF @MediaTypeID > 0 or @MediaGroupID > 0
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + 'INNER JOIN (SELECT lmc.ID FROM Lookup_MediaChannels (nolock) lmc 
                       INNER JOIN Lookup_SonarMediaTypes (nolock) lsmt ON lmc.SonarMediaTypeID = lsmt.ID
                       WHERE (ISNULL('+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@MediaTypeID) +',0) = 0 OR lsmt.ID = '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@MediaTypeID) +') 
                         AND (ISNULL('+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@MediaGroupID)+',0) = 0 OR lsmt.SonarMediaGroupID = '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@MediaGroupID) +'))t ON t.ID = lmc.ID '
```

I tried to convert them first and use a variable instead of the convert calls like below

```
IF @MediaTypeID > 0 or @MediaGroupID > 0
       BEGIN
       SET @TypeID = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@MediaTypeID)
       SET @GroupID = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@MediaGroupID)
          SET @SQL = @SQL + 'INNER JOIN (SELECT lmc.ID FROM Lookup_MediaChannels (nolock) lmc 
                                   INNER JOIN Lookup_SonarMediaTypes (nolock) lsmt ON lmc.SonarMediaTypeID = lsmt.ID
                                   WHERE (ISNULL('+ @TypeID +',0) = 0 OR lsmt.ID = '+ @TypeID +') 
                                   AND (ISNULL('+ @GroupID+',0) = 0 OR lsmt.SonarMediaGroupID = '+ @GroupID +'))'
       END
```

but it gave me this error

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',0) = 0 OR lsmt.ID = ' to data type int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are trying to convert the variables MediaTypeID and MediaGroupID from int to varchar. That operation does not fail, it just doesn't happen. Problem is that both are still integers, that you are trying to add in the dynamic code causing the error. So what i did was to declare 2 new variables, that should fix the problem. If you look into the code you didn't include, you should notice that MediaTypeID and MediaGroupID are both numeric most likely integers.

```
IF @MediaTypeID > 0 or @MediaGroupID > 0
BEGIN
DECLARE @TypeID2 VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @GroupID2 VARCHAR(10)

SET @TypeID2 =  NULLIF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@MediaTypeID ), 0)
SET @GroupID2 = NULLIF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@MediaGroupID), 0)
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'INNER JOIN (SELECT lmc.ID FROM Lookup_MediaChannels (nolock) lmc 
                   INNER JOIN Lookup_SonarMediaTypes (nolock) lsmt ON lmc.SonarMediaTypeID = lsmt.ID
  WHERE '+ 
  coalesce( @TypeID2 +' = lsmt.ID', '1=1') +
  coalesce( 'AND' + @GroupID2+' = lsmt.SonarMediaGroupID', '') + ')t ON t.ID = lmc.ID '
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can re-craft your `WHERE` clause to eliminate the ISNULLS in the body of the query by moving them up to the variable calculation at the beginning of the code block.

So, instead of:

```
SET @TypeID = CONVERT(Varchar(10), @MediaTypeID)
```

do:

```
SET @TypeID =  CAST( COALESCE(@MediaTypeID, 0) AS Varchar)
```

That way, the conversion doesn't have to happen in the query itself.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting may have been caused by NULL @MediaTypeID or @MediaGroupID values because your code does not properly handle NULLS.

However, having an OR condition like that in the WHERE clause is bad for performance because it prevents the query optimizer from using an index. I would suggest rewriting it to avoid the OR (which also cuts down on the number of CONVERTs:

```
IF @MediaTypeID > 0 or @MediaGroupID > 0
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + 'INNER JOIN (SELECT lmc.ID FROM Lookup_MediaChannels (nolock) lmc 
                                INNER JOIN Lookup_SonarMediaTypes (nolock) lsmt ON lmc.SonarMediaTypeID = lsmt.ID 
                                WHERE 1=1 '
    IF @MediaTypeID > 0 
        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND lsmt.ID = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@MediaTypeID)

    IF  @MediaGroupID > 0
        SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND lsmt.SonarMediaGroupID = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@MediaGroupID)

    SET @SQL = @SQL + ') t ON t.ID = lmc.ID '
END
```